# Dbms_scheduler repeat interval maximum value

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

In documentaion (11g, 12c) we read:

> This specifies a positive integer representing how often the recurrence repeats. The default is 1, which means every second for secondly, every day for daily, and so on. The maximum value is 99.

In documentaion (10g) we read:

> ... same ... The maximum value is 999.

But in Oracle 10g and 12c real maximum is 7999 for SECONDLY frequency. Where is true? I can't find some errata docs.

Comment: What is your problem? The documentation surely is not the best part of the Oracle Scheduler ....

Comment: @ik_zelf I want to know how dangerous to use values between 1 and 7999 seconds in INTERVAL value for SECONDLY frequency. My users can set schedule interval by yourself via API.

Answer (score 0):

A larger value for secondly is less of a problem compared to the lower values. A job that runs very frequently uses resources more often than a job that runs only a few times per day (same job).
Monitoring is an important part of using Oracle Scheduler.
Did job creations succeed?
Did job runs succeeed?
How many ran concurrently?
Did other users get problems because of the jobs load?